# How to remove awk space while printing with values

Tags: awk

I have a test.csv

```
#cat test.csv
a.b.c.d
a.b
a.b.c
a-a.b.c          
a-a.b
```

(1) I am trying to print all values after 1st dot and (2) last dot must not be printed.

I try below but it come up with spaces, actual file is about 1 billion records, any idea how can I print without dot,

```
#cat test.csv | awk -F. '{print $2,".",$3}' 
b . c
b . 
b . c
b . c
b .
```

Desired output

```
b.c.d
b
b.c
b.c          
b
```

Comment: "print all values after 1st dot" > The expected output of the first line does not agree with your description

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks, i just correct that

Comment: [edit] your question to either explain `last dot must not be printed` or remove that statement because it's not clear what you mean by that and the last dot on each line of your input does show up in your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's|[^.]*\.||' test.csv
b.c.d
b
b.c
b.c
b
```

`[^.]` means anything but a `.` character. `\.` is the `.` character (needs to be escaped because it has a special meaning in regexes).

Answer (score 3):

The spaces in your output are because you're telling awk to add spaces. Each `,` in the print statement is you telling awk to add the value of the `OFS` variable (a single blank char by default) in that position in the output. Instead of:

```
awk -F. '{print $2,".",$3}'
```

Try either of these:

```
awk -F. '{print $2"."$3}'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {print $2,$3}'
```

To get the output you want with awk though would be:

```
awk '{sub(/[^.]*\./,"")}1'
```

but I'd really suggest you use the tool designed for this task, cut:

```
cut -d'.' -f2-
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF>=3{print $2,$3;next} NF==2{print $2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{               ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program from here.
  FS=OFS="."         ##Setting FS and OFS as DOT(.) here.
}
NF>=3{               ##Checking condition if number of fields greater than 3 then do following.
  print $2,$3        ##Printing 2nd and 3rd field values here.
  next               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF<=2{               ##Checking if number of fields is lesser than 2 then do following.
  print $2           ##Printing 2nd field here.
}
' Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```